# Вернуть заданное количество символов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица по данным цен на авиабилеты. 
Из-за того, что дата и время написана в неправильном формате, то excel не форматирует по дате. 
Подскажите, как оставить в столбце SearchDate только первые 10 символов через python и pandas.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формат-то как раз самый правильный) А при чём тут Python и Pandas?

Comment: Excel не воспринимает время. А данных 280 тысяч и руками убрать время и оставить дату очень сложно

Comment: вы можете привести ваш пример в виде текста, так, чтобы мы могли ими воспользоваться - набирать текст с картинки не хочется... И еще приведите вывод команды: `print(df.dtypes)`, где `df` -имя вашего DataFrame'а

Comment: Вы хотите с помощью питона прочитать значение из ячеек "SearchDate", обрезать и сохранить новые значения укороченные до 10 знаков? (пример 2011-06-15)

Comment: @DmitryErohin, если я правильно понял - данные уже в Pandas DataFrame (это модуль для обработки данных для Python)

Comment: @MaxU ясно, спасибо.

Comment: @DmitryErohin Именно так 2011-06-15, вы правильно поняли

Comment: @GRZZLY, это у вас на картинке Excel файл или Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @MaxU Pandas DataFrame

Comment: @GRZZLY, OK, а `dtype` какой у `SearchDate`?

Comment: @MaxU SearchDate    datetime64[ns]
Price                float64

Comment: @GRZZLY, и вам надо все это сохранить в Excel файл, так чтобы даты были в формате `YYYY-MM-DD` -  я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @MaxU Да, он и сейчас в xlsx формате. Я потом буду агрегировать данные по дате(средняя стоимость по дневной дате)

Comment: @GRZZLY, т.е. вам надо что-то вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667382/211923)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SearchDate': pd.to_datetime(['2011-06-15 10:03:45.000000','2011-06-15 10:13:13.000000']),
    'Price': [11444, 13779.5]
})[['SearchDate', 'Price']]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("d:/temp/test.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd',
                        date_format='yyyy-mm-dd')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [29]: df.SearchDate.dt.normalize()
Out[29]:
0   2011-06-15
1   2011-06-15
Name: SearchDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]  # дата с "обнуленным" временем

In [30]: df.SearchDate.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[30]:
0    2011-06-15
1    2011-06-15
Name: SearchDate, dtype: object  # дата в виде строки
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!

Comment: Небольшое уточнение, можно ли удалить время, потому что он все равно отображается в ячейках.

Comment: @GRZZLY, смотрите UPDATE - вам нужно будет заменить: `df.SearchDate = df.SearchDate.dt.normalize()` или вторым способом

Comment: @GRZZLY, было бы гораздо проще если бы вы указали пример данных в виде текста и выходные данные (включая агрегирование)